# Why the elements in my ListView show different on different devices?

Tags: android

I have a ListView.

This is the XML for the item of the ListView:

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/mainbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mainbackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/signlist" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/mainbackground"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventname"
                style="@style/N1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="mcdonalds" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/N1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventtype"
                style="@style/N3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventdate"
            style="@style/N2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Sun 15 Oct2013" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/lines" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Now, the point is that the same ListView show different (wrong) on some devices:

This is how it shows on a Samsung Galaxy Ace (API 10)

**And it is OK!!!**

[image]

---

This is how it shows on my Nexus 7 (API 17)

**And it is NOT OK!!!  :-(((**

[image]

This is the N1 style:

```
<style name="N1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#252525</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">20sp</item>
</style>
```

This is the N1 style for "values-sw600dp"

```
<style name="N1">
    <item name="android:textColor">#252525</item>
    <item name="android:typeface">sans</item>
    <item name="android:textSize">30sp</item>
</style>
```

Comment: paster you `style="@style/N1"` code

Answer (score 1, accepted):

SOLVED!!

```
<LinearLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="wrap_content"
android:background="@color/mainbackground"
android:orientation="vertical" >

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:background="@color/mainbackground"
    android:gravity="center_vertical"
    android:orientation="horizontal"
    android:padding="10dp" >

    <ImageView
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:src="@drawable/signlist" />

    <LinearLayout
        android:layout_width="0dp"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content"
        android:layout_weight="0.8"
        android:background="@color/mainbackground"
        android:orientation="vertical" >

        <LinearLayout
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:orientation="horizontal" >

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventname"
                style="@style/N1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:paddingLeft="10dp"
                android:text="mcdonalds" />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/textView2"
                style="@style/N1"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text=" " />

            <TextView
                android:id="@+id/eventtype"
                style="@style/N3"
                android:layout_width="wrap_content"
                android:layout_height="wrap_content"
                android:text="" />
        </LinearLayout>

        <View
            android:layout_width="fill_parent"
            android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

        <TextView
            android:id="@+id/eventdate"
            style="@style/N2"
            android:layout_width="wrap_content"
            android:layout_height="wrap_content"
            android:paddingLeft="10dp"
            android:text="Sun 15 Oct2013" />
    </LinearLayout>
</LinearLayout>

<LinearLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical" >

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="@dimen/spazio" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="@color/lines" />

    <View
        android:layout_width="fill_parent"
        android:layout_height="1dp"
        android:background="#FFFFFF" />
</LinearLayout>

</LinearLayout>
```

Comment: it doesn't look like you changed anything?